# rmagick CarrierWave 'Failed to manipulate with rmagick' for pdf file

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, ruby-2.1

I am trying to use rmagick to convert to pdf, but i am getting the error:

```
[Failed to manipulate with rmagick, maybe it is not an image? Original Error: FailedToExecuteCommand `"gs" -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 "-sDEVICE=pngalpha" -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 "-r72x72"  "-sOutputFile=/tmp/magick-2797WnVJ4aTtWnrf%d" "-f/tmp/magick-2797SHrLmrQNlfJP" "-f/tmp/magick-2797RE8ma6T4j70p"' (-1) @ error/delegate.c/ExternalDelegateCommand/461]
```

My ImageMagic config:

```
convert -list configure
```

> CONFIGURE      ../../configure  '--build=x86_64-linux-gnu' '--includedir=${prefix}/include' '--mandir=${prefix}/share/man' '--infodir=${prefix}/share/info' '--localstatedir=/var' '--libdir=${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' '--libexecdir=${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' '--disable-maintainer-mode' '--disable-dependency-tracking' '--prefix=/usr' '--libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--with-includearch-dir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/' '--mandir=/usr/share/man'convert -list configure '--infodir=/usr/share/info' '--docdir=/usr/share/doc/imagemagick' '--with-modules' '--with-gs-font-dir=/usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts' '--with-magick-plus-plus' '--with-djvu' '--with-wmf' '--without-gvc' '--enable-shared' '--without-dps' '--without-fpx' '--with-perl' '--with-perl-options=INSTALLDIRS=vendor' '--x-includes=/usr/include/X11' '--x-libraries=/usr/lib/X11' '--without-rsvg' '--cache-file=../../config.cache' '--without-gcc-arch' '--disable-silent-rules' '--with-quantum-depth=16' 'build_alias=x86_64-linux-gnu' 'CFLAGS=-g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security' 'LDFLAGS=-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--as-needed' 'CPPFLAGS=-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' 'CXXFLAGS=-g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security'

```
CPPFLAGS       -I/usr/include/ImageMagick-6
CXX            g++
CXXFLAGS       -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -pthread
DEFS           -DHAVE_CONFIG_H
DELEGATES      bzlib djvu mpeg fftw fontconfig freetype jbig jng jpeg lcms lqr lzma openexr pango png ps tiff wmf x xml zlib
DISTCHECK_CONFIG_FLAGS 'CFLAGS=-g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security' 'CPPFLAGS=-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' 'LDFLAGS=-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--as-needed' --disable-deprecated --with-quantum-depth=16 --with-umem=no --with-autotrace=no --with-dps=no --with-fpx=no --with-gslib=no --with-fontpath= --with-gs-font-dir=/usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts --with-gvc=no --with-rsvg=no=
FILTER_PATH    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ImageMagick-6.8.9/modules-Q16/filters
INCLUDE_PATH   /usr/include/ImageMagick-6
LDFLAGS        -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--as-needed -L/usr/lib/X11
LIBRARY_PATH   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ImageMagick-6.8.9
LIBS           -llcms2 -lfreetype -llqr-1 -lglib-2.0 -lfftw3 -lfontconfig -lfreetype -lXext -lSM -lICE -lX11 -lXt -llzma -lbz2 -lz -lltdl -lm -lgomp
PCFLAGS        -fopenmp -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16
```

I've tried the following:

1. wget http://www.imagemagick.org/download/ImageMagick.tar.gz
2. tar xvfz ImageMagick.tar.gz
3. cd ImageMagick
4. `./configure --with-bzlib=yes --with-fontconfig=yes --with-freetype=yes --with-gslib=yes --with-gvc=yes --with-jpeg=yes --with-jp2=yes --with-png=yes --with-tiff=yes --with-pdf=yes --disable-shared`
5. make
6. sudo make install
7. sudo ldconfig /usr/local/lib
8. run again "convert -list configure" and look at changes

but the error keeps the same.